# Wrong mean, mode and median values being displayed

Tags: google-earth-engine, spatial-statistics, sentinel-5p

I am using this code to extract mean values as well as spatial distribution, but I know for a fact that the max values are wrong as I can see greater values using inspector tool makes me doubt the mean and median values.

I can't seem to figure out why this is happening.

```
var ROI = ee.FeatureCollection("users/enigma_srl/sngkatniumaria");
    // define a 'collection' of images
    var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/NRTI/L3_NO2')
    .select('NO2_column_number_density')
    .filterBounds(ROI)
    .filterDate('2021-03-01', '2021-06-30')
    
    // .filterDate('2019-11-01', '2019-11-30');
    // .filterDate('2019-12-01', '2019-12-31');
    // .filterDate('2020-01-01', '2020-01-31');
    // .filterDate('2020-02-01', '2020-02-29');
    // .filterDate('2020-03-01', '2020-03-31');
    // .filterDate('2020-04-01', '2020-04-30');
    ;
    
    // The region of interest - a planar rectangle around London/S.England.
    
    
    var no2Image = collection.mean()
    .clip(ROI)
    ; // mean across each period
    print('NO2 image', no2Image); // debug info in console
    var band_viz = {
    min: 0,
    max: 0.0006,
    
    palette: ['black', 'blue', 'purple', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']
    };
    
     // set map to hybrid backdrop
    Map.centerObject(ROI, 8); // zoom in to the defined area
    Map.addLayer(no2Image, band_viz, 'Sentinel 5P NRT N02 - Nov 2019');
    
    var meanValue = no2Image.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      geometry: ROI.geometry(),
      crs: 'EPSG:4326',
      crsTransform: [1,0,0,0,1,0],
    });    
    print('Mean concentration:', meanValue)
    
    var maxValue = no2Image.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
      geometry: ROI.geometry(),
      crs: 'EPSG:4326',
      crsTransform: [1,0,0,0,1,0],
      
    });    
    print('Max concentration:', maxValue)
    
    var medianValue = no2Image.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.median(),
      geometry: ROI.geometry(),
      crs: 'EPSG:4326',
      crsTransform: [1,0,0,0,1,0],
    });    
    print('Median concentration:',medianValue)
    
    // Create a task that you can launch from the Tasks tab.
    // commented out here - but saves off geoTIFF files
     Export.image.toDrive({
     image: no2Image.clip(ROI),
     description: 'NO2_image_export',
     folder: 'GEE',
     fileNamePrefix: 'NO2_change',
     region: ROI,
     fileFormat: 'GEOTIFF',
     scale: 1000
     
    });
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/d2be50a12f5ed2209ac455464fcd9bd9

Comment: Your assets are not shared. Try to set scale on your `reduceRegion()` calls.